# Software for robot parts interaction modeling

Tags: software

I'm robotic engineer, using OpenSCAD to model robotic components (gears, pulleys, parts, etc). But I need an application to model the physics and interaction of the components (for i.e. how will robot move if I rotate a given gear).

So, is there any software I can use for modelling interactions in Linux? Google SketchUp is good, but I can't use it in Linux.

Comment: Depending on the power of your desktop, you could try to run SketchUp with `wine`, `bochs` or maybe `vmware`.

Comment: I'm running it in VirtualBox, but It's not always convenient. I need native decision.

Comment: And when I'm running it in VirtualBox, I need use pirate copy of WindowsXP in it.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered modeling the robot in a simulator? [V-REP](http://www.v-rep.eu/) is new and quite good, having lots of examples robots from other famous projects. [Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/) is another popular one that is usually used with ROS (although V-REP also has ROS support). Both run on linux and are open-source.

Comment: V-REP is quite impressive (at least the videos)

Comment: Is it possible to import/export STL in V-REP (for 3d printing) and simulate chain pulleys and gears?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I've only briefly used V-REP and am not familiar with all of its features. Sorry!